# Using qemu-kvm images with Mac OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

i am a big fan of qemu-kvm, i've several instances running on servers running ubuntu linux. I now wonder if it's anyhow possible to use a virtual server image on an Mac OS X machine. Either by running qemu on OSX or by running any other virtual machine? Is there any possibility?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu should be able to use qemu but it will be SLOW without without either k-qemu or kvm (neither of which is available in OS X to my knowledge). What you can do is take a qemu image and convert it to use in ESX/VBox.